# SOAP::LIte on_fault not overriding default error handling

Tags: perl, soap, wsdl

Centos 5 |
Perl 5.10.0 |
SOAP::Lite 1.20

Having read the documentation for using on_fault as an override to the default error handling of SOAP::Lite, I would expect the following code to use the callback for error handling processing.  However, what I see happening is the default is being used

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use SOAP::Lite;

my $log #calls to Log4Perl
my $soapServer = "http://somelocation/services/GdeWsOpenAPI?wsdl"
my $soap = new SOAP::Lite();
    $soap->on_fault( \&soapError );
    $soap->service($soapServer);

sub soapError {
     my($soap, $res) = @_;
     my $message = ref $res ? $res->faultstring : $soap->transport->status;
     $log->write( "fatal connection error to server $SoapServer: $message.", 0);
print STDERR "connection error: $message\n";
exit 1;
}
```

Output is:
Service description 'http://somelocation/services/GdeWsOpenAPI?wsdl' cannot be loaded: 500 Can't connect to somelocation:80

Expected (because of transport error):
connection error: Service description 'http://somelocation/services/GdeWsOpenAPI?wsdl' cannot be loaded: 500 Can't connect to somelocation:80

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback is for problems that occur when making a SOAP call. You haven't gotten that far.

```
my $soap = SOAP::Lite->new();
$soap->on_fault( \&soapError );

eval { $soap->service($soapServer); 1 }
    or die("Can't initialize the web service: $@");
```

Answer (score -1):

A fault is a special type of response from the server saying "something went wrong with your request". What's happening there is not a fault, it's failing to connect to the server at all. You might want to use Try::Tiny for this.

Comment: That's not true. Failing to connect to the server calls the fault handler ...if it happens as part of a soap call. The error that is happening is happening far before the SOAP call is even attempted.